# Trying to code Kepler's law as a function of Time (has work-around)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, simulations, software

*NOTE: This problem has an acceptable workaround. It's a (fun?) question for mathematicians, but since performance is not a huge issue here, there's no major necessity for the problem to be solved.*

I'm doing my best to interpret Kepler's law into animation code from wikipedia as seen here:

[Wikipedia - Kepler's Law as a Funciton of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Position_as_a_function_of_time)

I got it to work exactly as expected with one exception: I expected apogee and perigee, (or time = 0 and time = half of the period), to line up with 0° and 180°, but the angle of the whole thing is off. I can change values for eccentricity and the semi-major axis and the offset angle is the same, but it changes when I change the value of P, the orbital period, and the smaller the value the farther off the angle. The workaround is to run it once at perigee to determine the angle of offset and subtract it from subsequent calculations. I am curious whether I made some error and this workaround isn't necessary. Here are screenshots of the equations and my code along with the results:

[image: Equations and Code]

[image: Example of Results]

Copied Code:

```
#The procedure for calculating the heliocentric polar coordinates (r,θ) of a planet as a function of the time t since perihelion
def Kepler(t, p, e, a):             #where t is the time since perilhelion, and p is the period, e is eccentricity, a is the semimajor axis
    n = (2*pi)/p                    #Compute the mean motion

    m = n*t                         #Compute the mean anomaly

    #----------------------         #Compute the eccentric anomaly E by solving Kepler's equation:                                
    E = 0; prE = 1; prprE = 2
    while E != prE and E != prprE:  #iterate until there is no change between iterations or it loops
        prprE = prE; prE = E
        E = m + e*sin(E)
        E = E + ((m+e*sin(E)-E)/(1-e*cos(E)))
        
    #----------------------         #Compute the true anomaly
    t = modf(t/p)[0]*p
    if t < p/2:
        θ = 2*atan(sqrt(((1+e)*pow(tan(E/2),2))/(1-e)))+2*pi*n
    else:
        θ = 2*atan(-sqrt(((1+e)*pow(tan(E/2),2))/(1-e)))+2*pi*n
        
    r = a*(1-e*cos(E))              #Compute the heliocentric distance r
    
    return [r, θ]
```

Comment: What are the parameters you are using to generate the animation? also, it seems weird to me that the iterative equations diverge (explode), I think there might be an issue with your solver. You should use one of the iterative procedures without alternation and have a converged result.

Comment: All 3 anomalies should equal 0° at the perihelion. BTW, you should almost always use `atan2(y, x)` rather than `atan(y/x)` because `atan2` gets the correct quadrant, and it can handle `x==0`. Also, when solving Kepler's equation iteratively, you can use the `E` of the previous orbit point as your initial approximation for the current point.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `E = m + e*sin(E)` in your Newton's method `while` loop. But your calculation of the true anomaly from the eccentric anomaly looks wrong, especially the `+2*pi*n`.

Comment: I can't seem to get any different behavior with atan2 in the script. The only quadrant problem I have is the second half of orbit, which I assume is necessary and the reason there's two forms of the true anomaly equation, one with a negative. I determine to use it when time is greater than half the period. Also, there's only one argument, so I end up using 1 in the second part, and never zero. Should I just use atan then?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you'd replied. You need to use the `@UserName` syntax. To use `atan2` on an equation of the form $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac pq\tan x\right)$ you can do `atan2(p * sin(x), q * cos(x))`. OTOH, i generally use this to convert eccentric anomaly to true anomaly: `arctan2(coecc*sin(E), cos(E)-ecc)`, where `ecc` is eccentricity, and `coecc=sqrt(1-ecc**2)`

Comment: @PM2Ring Amazing! Thank you so much for everything!